# Замена подстроки (переменной) в строке

Tags: php, переменные, строки

Есть строка. Требуется заменить в ней одно слово на другое. Сложности возникают, когда нужно не просто одно слово на другое поменять, а когда их становится много. В итоге требуется поменять в строке содержание одной переменной на другую. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил. Если нет — пишите, постараюсь лучше пояснить. Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понятно, давайте пример.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам надо делать это через цикл, но все же дайте пример.

Comment: Есть строка: "Буря мглою небо кроет".
Нужно заменить слово НЕБО на <b>НЕБО</b>.
Это частный случай. По факту у меня много строк и много "слов".
Так понятнее? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = str_replace("НЕБО", "<b>НЕБО</b>", $text);
```

---

```
$search = array('1', '2');
$replace = array('один', 'два');
$text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

---

```
str_ireplace - регистро-независимый вариант
```

---

Держите регуляркой:

```
$t = 'небо';
$text = 'буря нЕбо';
$text = preg_replace("/(".$t.")/iu", "<i>\\1</i>", $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Вот тут и загвоздка у автора
"Сложности возникают, когда нужно не просто одно слово на другое поменять, а когда их становится много."

Comment: @abibock_un, изменил.

Comment: preg_replace($regularExpression, $replacement, $subject); 

И используйте в регулярке \i

Comment: @abibock_un, изменил.

Comment: str_ireplace не работает. Вот код: $text = 'Буря мглою небо кроет';
$search = array('буря', 'небо');
$replace = array('БУРЯ', 'НЕБО');
$text = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $text;

Comment: @abibock_un, special for you, хотя странно, что у вас не работает `str_ireplace`, я запустил - у меня норм.

Comment: У меня прекрасно работает str_ireplace, проверьте что у вас с кодировкой

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "проверить что с кодировкой"? Документ в UTF.

Comment: 100% неправильная кодировка, мои варианты оба рабочие, сам тестил. В скайп добавить, и помогу.

Comment: @manitikyl, вполне вероятно, что проблемы на моей стороне. Как поправить кодировку и где? Вы про это или про что-то другое?

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">